# percentage width with percentage padding

Tags: html, css

I have the layout here: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/susXf/11/

In Chrome and Firefox you'll notice there is a 1 pixel gap between the edge of the red box and the image. In IE 8, this isn't there (as expected).

This does not happen if I specify the width and padding using pixels.

My guess, although I cannot be sure, is due to the calculations of percentages and how numbers are rounded. The 6% for the padding works out to be 20.94px, the width of the p works out as 328.06. Assuming both are rounded down (despite the fact the first should be rounded up), then the total width is 348px, which seems to be the cause of the problem. IE is maybe more intelligent and rounds up correctly?

Nevertheless, has anyone else come across the same situation and found a fix?

Comment: I see no gap in Chrome 13.0.782.220 m

Comment: That's the same version as me.... :( What about a different browser?

Comment: Hmm, if I use Firefox and resize the window I can see it fixing and breaking on -almost- alternating pixels, so one state it will be fine, drag the window one pixel wider or smaller and it will break. Chrome does not do the same, it is always broken.

Comment: Looks the same in FF too, I'll try IE9 to make sure.

Comment: Looks fine in IE9 too. Are you sure your monitor's resolution is set perfectly?

Comment: Looks fine in my Chrome 13.0.782.218 m

Comment: What screen resolutions are people using? I'm on a 24" 1920x1080p. Despite similar browser versions, I can't see this as a screen issue, I have perfect clarity and can see individual pixel lines (not a line spread across 2 pixels and AA applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually caused because of your parent element. You have the width set at `349px`. Some browsers, depending on available screen space, will round up or down by default.

It's generally a good practice to use nice widths when using percentages.

---

**Solution**: http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/susXf/29/

This solution allows for an unset, arbitrary image width to define the wrapping element's width and thus, the child `span` and `<p>` widths. This achieves the goal of the OP on the fly, without having to manually enter custom classes or width declarations.

---

**CSS**

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.videoThumb {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}

.videoThumb .details {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: red;
}
.details p {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 4%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoThumb">
    <img src="http://www.chainreactiondisco.com/images/disco_panel_02_01.jpg">
    <span class="details">
        <p><!-- containing element for black box -->
            Watch<br />
            Signature Manager vs. Mail Dislcaimers
        </p>
    <span><!-- /details -->
</div><!-- /videoThumb -->
```

***NOTE***

If you are planning on using any `<p>` tags inside `span.details`, I'd suggest changing your css a bit. All you need to do is change `.details p {}` to `.details span {}`. Then go to your HTML and change the `<p>` tags to `<span>` tags.

Comment: This fixes my problem in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE8 I am now seeing the red box expand beyond the width of the image by 1px. No doubt if I worked out the maths there would be similar problems with the numbers. Are you able to reproduce the error I am seeing? Just to confirm it's not just me as Kyle seems unable to see the same thing

Comment: Ok well the numbers should add up correctly, so not sure why I see it expanding wider than the box.

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the error at all. But since your parent element is a fixed width... why not have the `p` element be a fixed width too? http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/susXf/23/

Comment: Hmm I had planned it to work such that I could have any size thumb and use the same script, but as you quite rightly point out I've gone and specified a width anyway so that makes that kind of flexibility somewhat redundant. As people seem to be struggling to reproduce the error anyway I may just call it a day here and take that solution! Thanks

Comment: Chris, wanted to let you know that I updated my answer with a solution for you.

Comment: Ooo that works very nicely, thank you! Can't mark it as answer twice I'm afraid but I can up vote it :P